# Парсер пишет разные параграфы одной статьи с новой строки, а все остальные данные просто дублирует. Как это можно исправить?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Парсер собирает контент, но вот записывает не так как надо. post_text разбивается на новые строчки в базе данных,разделение идет по абзацам, в то время как остальные переменные просто дублируются. Что я сделал не так и как это можно исправить?

```
def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    news = soup.find('div', class_='article-list').find_all('h3', class_='article-list__item-title')
    for new in news:
        try:
            title = new.find('a',class_= 'link_nodecor').text.strip()
            print(title)
        except:
            title = ''
        try:
            url = 'https://example.ru' + new.find('a',class_= 'link_nodecor').get('href')
            print(url)
            post = requests.get(url).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(post,'lxml')
            articles = soup.find('div',class_='article').find_all('p')
            for article in articles:
                try:
                    post_text = article.text
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO news VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (title, post_text, url))
                    cursor.commit()  
                    print(post_text)
                except:
                    post_text = ''
        except:
            url = ''
```

Comment: а где ваш вопрос?

Comment: Да, пропустил вопрос. Что я сделал не так и как это можно исправить в этом случае?

Comment: попробуйте на разных данных, если не заработает, приведите эти примеры здесь, а то не очень понятно всё равно

Comment: Думаю без кода разметки тут трудно что посоветовать, либо ссылки

Comment: Все понятно, такая же ошибка была когда только начинал писать. Обнуляйте переменные!!!

Comment: Если вы укажите ссылку на сайт, помощь будет более развернутой